# 2010 Mac Mini Server- Boot loop then blank screen

Tags: mac, startup, mac-mini

My 2010 Mac Mini Server won’t start up. It powers on with the fan running high, shuts off right away, turns back on with the fan running high and stays on but doesn’t show anything on the screen or boot up. I’m not sure if this is boot looping because the HDMI doesn’t display an Apple logo at any point so I don’t know if it ever starts booting.

Specs:
Mac Mini Mid 2010 Server
2.66 Intel Core 2 Duo
4GB Memory
2x500GB Hard Drives

Comment: Other than just doing a regular boot, have you tried booting with extensions off? booting to Recovery Mode? Resetting NVRAM/PRAM?

Comment: Can you boot to a different OS on an external, or to Recovery mode? If it won't boot to another OS, then that would suggest a hardware problem.